# How to read 1-bit bmp from uchar buffer to cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, mfc

Here is a code, for reading bmp files and convert it to ImplImage class.
And I know that there is simple way (ImplImage("filepath")).

```
 CFile File;
char *ReadBuffer; // Pointer to read buffer
char *OutputBuffer; // Pointer to output buffer
BITMAPFILEHEADER BmpFileHeader;
unsigned int BmpHeadSize;
char *BmpHeadPtr;

File.Open(FileName);
SrcFile.Read(&BmpFileHeader, sizeof(BmpFileHeader);
BmpHeadSize = BmpFileHeader.bfOffBits - sizeof(BmpFileHeader);
BmpHeadPtr = new char[BmpHeadSize];

File.Read(BmpHeadPtr, BmpHeadSize);
BmpInfoPtr = (BITMAPINFOHEADER*)BmpHeadPtr;

ReadBuffer = new char[BmpInfoPtr->biSizeImage];

SrcFile.Read(ReadBuffer, BmpInfoPtr->biSizeImage);

OutputBuffer = new char[BmpInfoPtr->biSizeImage];
for (i = 0; i < IMAGE_HEIGHT; i++)
{
    //Use this line if the bitmap is 24 bit
        memcpy(&OutputBuffer[(IMAGE_HEIGHT - i - 1) * IMAGE_WIDTH * 3],
            &ReadBuffer[i * IMAGE_WIDTH * 3], IMAGE_WIDTH * 3);

}

memcpy(m_Ipl->imageData, OutputBuffer, BmpInfoPtr->biSizeImage);
```

How could I read 1-bit bmp image? It works fine with 24-bit and 8-bit.
Help please:)

Comment: To start with, maybe format the question so that we can read your code?

Comment: @BobbyDillanl instead of just writing "good idea" you shoud [edit] your question and _actually_ format your code correctly.

Comment: @MichaelWalz and what wrong with the question?

Comment: The formatting (or indentation) of the code in your question is horrible. If your code is formatted correctly, you'll get most likely more answers as many people just pass on when they see poorly formatted code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz ok

Answer (score 0):

Open the bitmap file with `LR_CREATEDIBSECTION` flag

```
HBITMAP hbmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImageW(0, L"test.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0,
    LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);

BITMAP bm;
GetObject(hbmp, sizeof(bm), &bm);
```

`bm.bmBits` will give access to bits. The size of bits is `bm.bmWidthBytes` x `bm.bmHeight`